# How to play video inside Angular-Bootstrap modal on open?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, html5-video

I'm loading videos dynamically based on a scope array of resources:

```
this.open = function (size, resource) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'playModal.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            resource: function () {
                return resource;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.rendered.then(function () {
        $('#resource-video')[0].play();
    });
};
```

As you can see, I'm using a jQuery selector to find the HTML5 video tag and play it in a callback on the modal's `rendered` event. What would be the "Angular way" to do this and maintain MVC discipline?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a raw JavaScript "class" that takes care of manipulating the video given the raw dom element. e.g.

```
function VideoControl(videoElement) {
  this.videoElement = videoElement;
}

VideoControl.prototype.play = function() {
  this.videoElement.play();
}

VideoControl.prototype.pause = function() {
  this.videoElement.pause();
}
```

In order to instantiate it and actually pass the dom element into it you could wrap it in a directive. e.g.

```
app.directive('videoControl', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var videoControlModel = $parse(attrs.videoControl);
      videoControlModel.assign(scope, new VideoControl(element[0]));
    }
  };
})
```

Then you can use this video control directive like this:

```
<button ng-click="videoControl.play()">Play</button>

<video  class="video" controls video-control="videoControl">
    ...
</video>
```

Here is a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/2epHSCo6wwyCplNhOBSe?p=preview

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to apply this to the modal callback scenario.

Comment: you would replace your `$('#resource-video')[0].play();` line of code with `$scope.videoControl.play()`. Or if you are using the controller as syntax `this.videoControl.play()`. the video-control directive assigns an instance of the VideoControl class to whatever variable name you pass into it

Comment: Thanks. I follow now. However, three functions plus a directive just to maintain separation of concerns is a tough pill to swallow. I'd like to see what other ideas come in.